# Django EC2 without Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What ever I search to find a tutorial to deploy a Django project on an EC2 instance, the only thing that I find is Amazon tutorial about how to deploy a Django project on Elastic Beanstalk.
Unfortunately EBS really restricts developers from using some packages, or changing settings as they like, and more importantly, every time you want to push your updated packages, it takes a fair amount of time to recover, which is really boring.

I'll appreciate any help or tutorial regarding how to deploy a Django project on EC2 without using EBS.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk simply wraps up the process of setting up the infrastructure for you which is convenient but certainly not mandatory.

You can easily deploy your Django project on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance by installing Django and other required tools.

Comment: I went through this webpage, but at the end of the day, when I went to the url, I saw a permission error. Also, I'll appreciate it if you suggest a more comprehensive Tutorial using Gunicorn, or similar frameworks.

Comment: [This](http://mytechtravails.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/installing-django-ngnix-gunicorn-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-12-04/) tutorial may help you.